# PostgreSQL import .sql file eror

Tags: sql, postgresql, out-of-memory

I wrote a python code to create a random 4gb sql file and created my 4gb file, then I was going to add it to the postgresql database with the following code:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d test -f C:\file.sql
```

but it gave me an error like:

```
error: out of memory postgresql
    DETAIL: Line buffer 0 bytes long cannot be extended by 1988953557 bytes.
```

My code:

```
    CREATE TABLE test1 (
      idcustomer int NOT NULL,
      testid varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      customername varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      custlastname varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      birthid varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      name varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      namee varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      named varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      phonenumber varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      testname varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      testnumber varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      testnamee varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
    );
    
    INSERT INTO test1 (idcustomer, testid, customername, custlastname, birthid, name, namee, named, phonenumber, testname, testnumber, testnamee) VALUES
    (1, '45645', 'jack', 'xxx', '151', 'nameeeee', 'testtt', 'xname', '585', 'xdname', '985', 'xs'),
    (2, '44524', 'adam', 'testt', '525', 'nameee', 'testttt', 'yname', '568', 'xdname', '854', 'xb'); --<< replace , with ;`
```

I couldn't find anything when I wrote this error what can I do to solve this error?

Comment: This is not going anywhere without the contents of `file.sql`. **Add to question as text**.

Comment: So where does the 4GB file enter into this?

Comment: If you really need to insert a **lot** of rows, it's more efficient to use the COPY statement where the data is streamed to the server. A single INSERT with a lot of rows simply exceeds the maximum length for a string (1GB) in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting multiple rows with a single INSERT
statement.

You didn't specify how many rows.

If that figure is more than a thousand or so,
you want to break it up into multiple INSERT
statements, each one inserting a bunch of rows.

---

You *can* issue a great many INSERTs as a single
atomic BEGIN; INSERT ...; INSERT ...; COMMIT; transaction.
But you might consider issuing a COMMIT
every now and again.
It all depends on your use case,
and on how hard you want the backend DB to work.
Isolation doesn't come for free; it has its costs.

---

If you're doing more than about ten COMMITs
per second on a long-running bulk transaction,
you're probably doing them a bit too often.
That is, depending on disk speed and WAN latency
to backend DB, reducing the commit rate might
net you increased throughput.

OTOH, if it's more than ten seconds between
COMMITs, definitely consider increasing the
commit rate, which means doing less work
between commits.
The giant transactions aren't helping you
send more rows per second to the disk.
And you'll have more lost work to re-do
if some transient error occurs partway through.

These are performance arguments, not correctness
arguments. If your use case truly does demand
isolation over large transactions, well,
so be it.

Comment: I think I got it, you're telling me to put this code again sometime between?:  INSERT INTO test1 (idcustomer, testid, customername, custlastname, birthid, name, namee, named, phonenumber, testname, testnumber, testnamee) VALUES

Comment: Your INSERT was too long. Insert fewer rows per INSERT statement. Also, while you're doing that, think about when the rows should be COMMITed. Could be after every INSERT, or after every hundred INSERTs, or just a single COMMIT when you're all done. Deferring the COMMIT longer means the backend has to buffer more data, for a potential ROLLBACK.

Comment: Large transactions aren't the problem here. A transaction inserting 1 million rows isn't really less efficient than a transaction insert 100 rows. The problem is that if you do that in one INSERT statement you are exceeding the maximum length of a single SQL statement. The frequent commits won't make this faster - splitting up the huge SQL string will. It's absolutely no problem inserting hundreds of millions of rows in a single transaction if that is done using the COPY command

Comment: Correct, large transactions aren't the problem here -- large lines are. But OP neglected to consider some sizes, and while he's at it he may as well consider the COMMIT rate. We know we're dealing with multi-gigabyte sets of rows, at least 4 GB in this particular case. It seems plausible that size_of_file > ram_in_server. So the final COMMIT will do much more disk I/O than necessary as it transfers from log over to the table blocks. Also, monitoring progress in another window with SELECT COUNT(*) can be very convenient.

Comment: A single commit when inserting a large number of rows does not generate more WAL segments than multiple commits with fewer rows. The (total) number of rows is relevant, not the number of rows per transaction.

Comment: Yes. I was concerned about cache hit ratios for amount of data that exceeds server RAM size. But I will grant you that it makes sense to table the discussion until benchmark timings are available.